# RadioGroup radio buttons changing state in ArrayAdapter ListView

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, android-arrayadapter, radio-group

I stressed out finding a proper solution for maintaining the state of radio buttons in the group in listView while scrolling through the questions. When ever I select a radio button and scroll through the list radio buttons get randomly select.

```
public class QuizAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Questions>{
        
            public QuizAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Questions> QuestionList){
        
                super(context,0,QuestionList);
            }
        
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View QuesView = convertView;
                if(QuesView == null){
                    QuesView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listlayout,parent,false);
                }
                final Questions tempQues = getItem(position);
        
                TextView question = (TextView) QuesView.findViewById(R.id.ques);
                TextView opt1 = (TextView) QuesView.findViewById(R.id.opt1);
                TextView opt2 = (TextView) QuesView.findViewById(R.id.opt2);
                TextView opt3 = (TextView) QuesView.findViewById(R.id.opt3);
                TextView opt4 = (TextView) QuesView.findViewById(R.id.opt4);;
                RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) QuesView.findViewById(R.id.rg);
                question.setText(tempQues.getQuestion());
                opt1.setText(tempQues.getOpt1());
                opt2.setText(tempQues.getOpt2());
                opt3.setText(tempQues.getOpt3());
                opt4.setText(tempQues.getOpt4());
        
                rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        
                        int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                        Questions question = getItem(position);
        //for checking current answer and correct answer
                            Log.v("QuizAdapter",radioButton.getText().toString()+" "+question.getAns());
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
            
            
                    return QuesView;
                }}
```

## ListLayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Question?"
        android:id="@+id/ques"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/rg">


        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="option 1"
            android:id="@+id/opt1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="option 2"
            android:id="@+id/opt2" />


        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="option 3"
            android:id="@+id/opt3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="option 4"
            android:id="@+id/opt4" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

## Question Class

```
    public class Questions {
    
        private String question;
        private String opt1;
        private String opt2;
        private String opt3;
        private String opt4;
        private String ans;
    
        public Questions(String question, String opt1, String opt2, String opt3, String opt4, String ans) {
            this.question = question;
            this.opt1 = opt1;
            this.opt2 = opt2;
            this.opt3 = opt3;
            this.opt4 = opt4;
            this.ans = ans;
        }
    
        public String getQuestion() {
            return question;
        }
    
        public String getOpt1() {
            return opt1;
        }
    
        public String getOpt2() {
            return opt2;
        }
    
        public String getOpt3() {
            return opt3;
        }
    
        public String getOpt4() {
            return opt4;
        }
    
        public String getAns() {
            return ans;
        }
        }
```

## ComputerQuiz Class

```
    public class ComputerQuiz extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_computer_quiz);
    
            ArrayList<Questions> computerQuestionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    
            computerQuestionsList.add(new Questions("You should save your computer from","Viruses","Time bombs","Worms", "" +
                    "All of the above","All of the above"));
    
            computerQuestionsList.add(new Questions("A light sensitive device that converts drawing, printed text or other " +
                    "images into digital form is","Keyboard","Scanner","MRE","Mouse","Scanner"));
    
            computerQuestionsList.add(new Questions("The basic architecture of computer was developed by","John Von Neumann",
                    "Charles Babbage","Blaise Pascal","Garden Moore","John Von Neumann"));
    
            computerQuestionsList.add(new Questions("In how many generations a computer can be classified?",
                    "3","4","5","6","5"));
    
            computerQuestionsList.add(new Questions("Fifth generation computers are based on",
                    "Programming Intelligence","System Knowledge","Holograms","Artificial Intelligence","Artificial Intelligence"));
    
            QuizAdapter ComQuestionList = new QuizAdapter(this,computerQuestionsList);
    
           final ListView comList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.comList);
            comList.setAdapter(ComQuestionList);
    
            View footer = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.footer_button,null,false);
            comList.addFooterView(footer);
            
        }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is mainly because of your Adapter object reusing.

So what you should do is, You should store the selected item some how and you should check and update when ever it called `getView` method in the view.

Example: if you selected the 2nd question as B and on your screen you have only 5 questions and answer. when you scroll more, Adapter will try to reuse the old object, may be your 8th question will try to reuse the object of your 2nd question, which has already answered.

For your case:
You can create one `HashMap<String, String>` in your `adapter` when ever user selected the question you can update the `HashMap`. and inside `getView` check every Question if already exists, then set the radio button selected and other button unselected.

Comment: Thankx for your reply but can you please give an example?